# Stack Overflow vs Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, accounts

I visit the **Stack Exchange** family of sites often but never created an account. Today I found myself looking at a question on **Stack Overflow** and decided to create an account. Honestly, I hadn't really recognized the distinction between **Exchange** and **Overflow** before. Strictly speaking, the question I was looking at probably belonged on **Exchange** (it was a question about vim).

Anyway, I decided to create an account and I chose to use GitHub login. I assumed the account would work on **Exchange** as well, but apparently it doesn't. At least not "out-of-the-box".

I'm not sure what the best course of action is at this point. I'm not really a developer so having an account that's solely linked to **Overflow** really doesn't make much sense. So if there's no way to make this account usable on **Exchange** I will probably delete it and just create a Google-linked account there. But I've never deleted an account that was linked to another account, so I also want to make sure deleting this account wouldn't have any effect on my GitHub account.

Comment: Can you add a Google login to this account in settings?

Comment: @Laurel I went to Settings > Access > Your Logins and to my surprise my Google account was already there. Does that mean if I go to Exchange and try to login with  using my Google account it will automatically be linked to this account?

Comment: I would try it. If you create an account that's not linked by accident it's not a big deal because it's a brand new account without any activity and you can delete it. If you do it right you should see "We will automatically link this account with your accounts on other Stack Exchange sites" before you create the account.

Comment: I see a [Stack Exchange account for you](https://stackexchange.com/users/7788834/alphaniner). If there's another you're talking about, please link it.

Comment: @Machavity OK, apparently I had created a SE account associated with my Google login but forgot about it. Still not sure how this account got linked to my Google account since I created it with my GitHub login, but I guess it really doesn't matter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Each user only has one Stack Exchange account (also known as the network account, e.g. [this is yours](https://stackexchange.com/users/7788834/alphaniner?tab=accounts)) and can join many sites that are considered as part of [the Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites), including those without "Exchange" in the name, e.g. Stack Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Ask Ubuntu, etc. The credentials used are shared across the whole network.

Also, Stack Exchange only provides 3 login options in general:

- Email & password
- Google account
- Facebook account

However, in addition to those, *a few sites also have exclusive login option*, e.g.:

- GitHub on Stack Overflow
- Launchpad on Ask Ubuntu

These login options are only available on their respective site, so a user cannot log in by GitHub on other sites (e.g. Vim.SE) and they must use another login option. To add login options, browse to [User profile - Settings - Your logins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/mylogins/current).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't recall authorizing my Google login to be used/associated when I created the account, so when I couldn't use my GitHub login on SE, I just assumed I couldn't have an account there.Edit: OK, now it's a bit more clear. Apparently I had created a SE account at some time in the past and forgotten about it.